# Add alert for all stocks in a watchlist

Tags: pine-script

I would like to add alert for all scripts in a watchlist at once. Is is possible to do so instead of adding alerts for each script one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noo it is not possible. You need to manually add alerts for each asset. Then there is also a limit for the number of alarms you can have depending on your subscription type which you can check from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/gopro/#compare).